# Recaptcha default theme displaying incorrectly

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, formatting, recaptcha

I've implemented recaptcha on my site using the default red style and it displays great on all browsers except IE 8.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [dovinoutlaw.com](http://www.dovinoutlaw.com/images/recaptcha.jpg))</sub>

What gives? Any idea?

I've done nothing to the formatting whatsoever. Just added the recaptcha to the page using JavaScript (jQuery) with standard plugin PHP validation (all proven working).

I don't even know where to start looking for a problem.

My jQuery code that loads the captcha after ajax load:

```
$("div#menu ul li a").click(function() {
    var ifContact = $(this).attr('href');   <!-- variable for contact page -->
    $('div#menu ul li a').removeClass("active").addClass("inactive");
    $(this).removeClass("inactive").addClass("active");   <!--changes nav buttons-->
    $('div#page_content').load(($(this).attr('href') + ' #content'), function(){ 
    if (ifContact == 'contact.html') {     <!--if we are on the contact page-->
       Recaptcha.create("key", "captcha", {
            theme: "red",
            callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        }); 
    }
    });
    return false;
    });
```

---

#### Solution

The div that recaptcha was in was positioned within a container div with `top:60px position:relative` via CSS. Changed to `position:absolute;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:
The div that recaptcha was in was positioned within a container div with top:60px position:relative via css. Changed to position:absolute;

Thanks to those who read and voted anyway!!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
ReCaptcha captcha = 
ReCaptchaFactory.newSecureReCaptcha(recapConfig.getPublickey(), 
recapConfig.getPrivatekey(), false);
```

with

```
ReCaptchaImpl recaptcha = new ReCaptchaImpl(); 
recaptcha.setIncludeNoscript(false); 
recaptcha.setPrivateKey(recapConfig.getPrivatekey()); 
recaptcha.setPublicKey(recapConfig.getPublickey()); 
recaptcha.setRecaptchaServer("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api");
```

Comment: This is nowhere to be found in my code or in the plugin php file. Not sure where you came up with this, but thanks.